# Export multiple listbox to excel or txt

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, csv

I have 5 `listboxes` and I want to export the content of these 5 lisboxes to excel. I want that these listboxes would be shown in 5 columns. *Listbox1[0]* should be in the same row like *listbox2[0]* and so on (*listbox3[0], listbox4[0], listbox5[0]*).

I tried to copy all items from listboxes to datagridview and then export to excell but I can only choose one datasource, I didnt found a way to copy all 5 listboxes items to 5 columns in datagridview.

EDIT:

I solved with this code (thanks to my friend). Just created a datatable, imported lists items into it and exported datable to csv.

```
    //create datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //create datatable columns
    dt.Columns.Add("title++", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("title",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("season_name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("episode_name", typeof(string));
    int rowCount = listBox1.Items.Count;

    //insert lists items into datatable columns
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["title++"] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
        row["title"] = listBox5.Items[i].ToString();
        row["season_name"] = listBox3.Items[i].ToString();
        row["episode_name"] = (listBox4.Items[i].ToString() + (" ") + listBox2.Items[i].ToString());

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    CreateCSVFile(dt, "output.csv");
    MessageBox.Show("Data exported.");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far as we also prefer to see some code.

Comment: Please try first! then let us know where you struggling so that others can help!

Comment: Sorry for my first crappy post. Issue is solved (i edited first post).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to write comma-separated values to a text file:

```
List<ListBox> listBoxes = new List<ListBox>();

foreach (Control c in Controls)
    if (c is ListBox)
        listBoxes.Add(c as ListBox);

int maxLineCount = listBoxes.Max(lb => lb.Items.Count);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < maxLineCount; rowIndex++)
{                
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < listBoxes.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        if (listBoxes[columnIndex].Items.Count > rowIndex)
            sb.Append(listBoxes[columnIndex].Items[rowIndex]);

        sb.Append(", ");
    }

    sb.AppendLine();
}

File.WriteAllText("c:\\mytext.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. I struggled with this code. Edited my first post to show how I ended up. But thank you all, its really fast reply in this community.